# which angle and axis to chose to get a 90 degrees angle between those 2 vectors

Tags: orthogonal

I am suddenly puzzled by ho to know (when in 3D) with respect to which axis is the vector being rotated when the dot product between then is =0. for example: if i rotate 90degrees (pi/2 radians) along Z axis the vector [1 1 1] i get : [-1 1 1] which is at about 70° from [1 1 1] according to the formula $\cos \theta = \frac{x^\top y}{||x||\cdot||y||}$ I think i cannot visualize (anymore) what is happening when it comes to 3D ans. Then can someone exmplain which rotation matrix (along which axis) and or axis is required to get the 90° angle between [1 1 1] and another vector [x y z], in other words how to find the Rotation Matrix in 3D to have $[x,y,z]^T=RMatrix*[1,1,1]^T  -> [1,1,1]^T * [x,y,z] = 0$ ?

---

to clarify, this is how i understand the setup with the Rotation Rz that i made around Z axis: see this drawing ---> [image]

Comment: *Which* "2 aforementioned vectors" are you asking about?

Comment: the [1 1 1] and [-1 1 1] vectors

Comment: OK, then please explain what you mean by "get the 90 degree angle" between them.  Bear in mind that if you simultaneously rotate them, their angle will remain unchanged.

Comment: sorry i think my question was indeed not very clear . I meant to have a 90 degrees between [1 1 1] and a vector [x y z] in such a way that their dot product is = 0. i fact i meant which Rotation matrix would you apply to [1 1 1] to get an orthogonal vector in 3D. (In 2D no probelm but as soon as i go to 3D it seems that it gets more complicated)

Comment: Use any rotation that moves the start vector into the plane perpendicular to it.  How to choose such a rotation? *Pick the final vector.*  The cross-product of the start vector and the final vector gives the axis of rotation.

Comment: thanks i forgot indeed about cross product which yields an orthogonal vector to the 2 others. However could you develop what you mean" by pick the final vector " ?

Comment: Oh sorry i think i get it, i simply can do the cross product of [1 1 1] with any 3D vector and the result of this cross prod will give me a vector orthogonal to [1 1 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cross product of any non-zero vector $\begin{bmatrix}  x  \\ y \\z \end{bmatrix} $with the vector $\begin{bmatrix}  1  \\ 1 \\1 \end{bmatrix}$, i.e.:  $\begin{bmatrix}  u  \\ v\\w \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}  1  \\ 1 \\1 \end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix}  x  \\ y \\z \end{bmatrix} $ then this vector $\begin{bmatrix}  u  \\ v\\w \end{bmatrix}$ will be orthogonal to $\begin{bmatrix}  1  \\ 1 \\1 \end{bmatrix}$.